# MUI 5 - Set Box Width Based on Viewport Size

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using MUI v5 and want to know if there's a way I can set the width based on a percentage of the viewport.

Currently, I'm hardcoding the width value to 250px for smaller screens and 500px for larger screens.

```
<Box component="img" sx={(theme) => ({
  [theme.breakpoints.down("md")]: {
     width: "250px",
  },
  [theme.breakpoints.up("md")]: {
     width: "500px",
  },
  })}
  alt="Diagram"
  src={diagram}
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `vw` or `vh`, which stands for viewport width/height. For example, `50vw` represents 50% of the viewport width .